How to add annotations to Plotly Scattermapbox/Choroplethmapbox figure
I want to create below map using Python Plotly.
Required Figure:

I'm able to create the hexagon layers, but I cannot add the annotations to the map and highlight a specific hexagon 8744a931effffff with a different colour. Here is my implementation below:
import plotly.graph_objects as go
import plotly.express as px
import pandas as pd
import h3

def create_plotly_map(final_data):
    # Create the base map
    fig = go.Figure()

    # Add choropleth layer for hexagons
    fig.add_trace(go.Choroplethmapbox(
        geojson=final_data['geometry'].__geo_interface__,
        locations=final_data.index,
        z=final_data['Forecast'],
        colorscale=['green', 'red'],
        zmin=final_data['Forecast'].min(),
        zmax=max(1, final_data['Forecast'].max()),
        marker_opacity=0.3,
        marker_line_width=0.5,
        colorbar=dict(title='Rescue Demand'),
        hoverinfo='none'
    ))

    # Function to add rectangle and text annotation
    def add_annotation(fig, x, y, text, color):
        fig.add_annotation(
            x=x,
            y=y,
            text=text,
            showarrow=False,
            font=dict(
                color=color,
                size=12
            ),
            bordercolor=color,
            borderwidth=200,
            borderpad=4,
            ax=0,  # Position relative to the x-axis
        ay=0,  # Position relative to the y-axis, adjust ay for vertical placement if needed
            bgcolor="rgba(255,255,255,0.7)"  # Semi-transparent background for better readability
        )

    # Add annotations for surge multipliers
    for idx, row in final_data.iterrows():
        color = row['color'][:7] if row['color'].startswith('#') and len(row['color']) == 9 else row['color']
        text = f"{row['surge_mul']:.2f}x"
        add_annotation(fig, row['lng'], row['lat'], text, color)


    hover_data = final_data[[
        'surge_mul', 'opportunity'
    ]]
    hover_text = hover_data.apply(
        lambda row: "<br>".join([

            f"Multiplier: {row['surge_mul']}",
            f"Opportunity: ${row['opportunity']}"
        ]),
        axis=1
    )

    fig.add_trace(go.Scattermapbox(
        lat=final_data['lat'],
        lon=final_data['lng'],
        mode='markers',
        marker=go.scattermapbox.Marker(size=0),  # Invisible markers for hover
        text=hover_text,
        hoverinfo='text',
        showlegend=False
    ))

    # Update layout
    fig.update_layout(
        mapbox_style="open-street-map",
        mapbox=dict(
            center=dict(
                lat=final_data['lat'].mean(),
                lon=final_data['lng'].mean()
            ),
            zoom=11
        ),
        font=dict(
            family="Rockwell",
            size=14),
        hoverlabel=dict(
            bgcolor="white",
            font_size=16,
            font_family="Rockwell"
        ),
        margin={"r":0,"t":0,"l":0,"b":0},
        height=600
    )

    return fig

# Assuming you have your final_data DataFrame ready
fig = create_plotly_map(final_data)
fig.show()

Sample data
data = pd.DataFrame({'h3_07': {0: '8744a9302ffffff',
  1: '8744a9311ffffff',
  2: '8744a930effffff',
  3: '8744a930cffffff',
  4: '8744a9315ffffff',
  5: '8744a9318ffffff',
  6: '8744a931dffffff',
  7: '8744a9306ffffff',
  8: '8744a9319ffffff',
  9: '8744a931effffff',
  10: '8744a931cffffff',
  11: '8744a9301ffffff',
  12: '8744a930affffff',
  13: '8744a9303ffffff',
  14: '8744a9300ffffff'},
 'Forecast': {0: 0,
  1: 0,
  2: 0,
  3: 0,
  4: 0,
  5: 0,
  6: 0,
  7: 0,
  8: 1,
  9: 0,
  10: 0,
  11: 1,
  12: 1,
  13: 1,
  14: 1},
 'surge_mul': {0: 1.12,
  1: 1.14,
  2: 2.03,
  3: 1.42,
  4: 1.74,
  5: 1.95,
  6: 1.34,
  7: 1.17,
  8: 1.0,
  9: 1.13,
  10: 1.0,
  11: 1.29,
  12: 1.0,
  13: 1.0,
  14: 1.14},
 'opportunity': {0: 0.0,
  1: 0.0,
  2: 0.0,
  3: 0.0,
  4: 0.0,
  5: 0.0,
  6: 0.0,
  7: 0.0,
  8: '-',
  9: 0.0,
  10: '-',
  11: 22.58,
  12: '-',
  13: '-',
  14: 19.95},
 'color': {0: '#008000ff',
  1: '#008000ff',
  2: '#008000ff',
  3: '#008000ff',
  4: '#008000ff',
  5: '#008000ff',
  6: '#008000ff',
  7: '#008000ff',
  8: '#ff0000ff',
  9: '#008000ff',
  10: '#008000ff',
  11: '#ff0000ff',
  12: '#ff0000ff',
  13: '#008080',
  14: '#ff0000ff'},
 'lat': {0: 28.68958635891766,
  1: 28.694991157953137,
  2: 28.72110573469225,
  3: 28.715694160659446,
  4: 28.67382864602292,
  5: 28.73191306462333,
  6: 28.72651203548175,
  7: 28.66841933038336,
  8: 28.747676222100004,
  9: 28.71615121919693,
  10: 28.710750939011273,
  11: 28.699934572325734,
  12: 28.742274441025884,
  13: 28.705345390585954,
  14: 28.68417629345379},
 'lng': {0: -81.54438913509742,
  1: -81.52227241812639,
  2: -81.57673277797278,
  3: -81.59886857103568,
  4: -81.52822959753617,
  5: -81.53247482786799,
  6: -81.55460152851583,
  7: -81.55034359990239,
  8: -81.54864440281916,
  9: -81.51631344624931,
  10: -81.53843287797946,
  11: -81.58268538919677,
  12: -81.57077837338699,
  13: -81.56055686069354,
  14: -81.5665104000335}})

import h3pandas
from h3 import h3
import geopandas as gpd
from shapely.geometry import Polygon, Point

def add_geometry(x):
    # Get geometry points
    points = h3.h3_to_geo_boundary(x, True)
    # Return a hexagon polygon
    return Polygon(points)

def add_geometry_to_hex(hex_df, HEX_RES_COL):
    # add geometry to the dataframe
    hex_df['geometry'] = hex_df[HEX_RES_COL].apply(lambda x : add_geometry(x))
    # Convert to geopandas dataframe
    hex_df = gpd.GeoDataFrame(hex_df)
    # return geopandas dataframe
    return hex_df
final_data = add_geometry_to_hex(data, "h3_07")


How can I add text annotations to the Scattermapbox/Choroplethmapbox figure??

The easiest way is to use mode=“makers+text” as the mode in scattertermapbox(). Simply changing the mode in the current code will add text centered on latitude and longitude. Also, at this time, python-plotly does not allow style sheets as string decoration, so I don't think rounded corner enclosures are possible.
